# How to disable underline to Material UI's datepicker in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

How can I disable showing underline to material-ui-pickers?

**sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2ykr7kwvz?from-embed

I want to removing underline to its `TextField`.

I tried

`disableUnderline={true}`

`underlineStyle={{display: 'non'}}`

`showingUnderline={false}`

But nothing works, How can I hide underline?

```
<DatePicker
    underlineStyle={{display: 'none'}}
    value={selectedDate}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    animateYearScrolling={false}
/>
```

Comment: After spending few times, I noticed that the `underline` UI is added into `:before` pseudo element. But there are no way to override it (I don't find any docs). I've opened a new issue request on their GitHub repo. https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/issues/423

Answer (score 46, accepted):

material-ui date-picker is a text field from the foundation and you can remove the underline simply using input-props

(DatePicker, TimePicker and DateTimePicker all will work this way)

```
<DatePicker
  value={selectedDate}
  InputProps={{
   disableUnderline: true,
  }}
  onChange={this.handleDateChange}
/>
```

find the example from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8z5j2oq8j9)

hope this will help you

Comment: `InputProps` is a prop of the `DatePicker`. It is a non recognizable prop, so it is passed down to the `TextField` component (as stated [here](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/demo/datepicker)).

Comment: Not just `DatePicker`, even it works on `TextField`. @Nadun and @Juntae, Thanks a lot for question and answer.

Comment: any idea how we can do the same for time picker ?

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you. Is there a reference in the docs somewhere on how this functionality works?

Comment: Word to the wise, `InputProps` is case sensitive and capitalized... which is odd among attributes/properties. Pesky invisible fail point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the previous solutions provided in this thread may be **deprecated**,Here is an **updated approach**

```
  <DatePicker
   slotProps={{
    textField: {
     variant: "standard",
      InputProps: { disableUnderline: true },
       },
              }}
            />
```