# How to prevent underline and slash symbols in material-ui/pickers?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

The material ui pickers for version mui version 4 shows underline and slash characters to separate day, month, year. Is there a way to remove those?

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
   margin="normal"
   id="date-picker-dialog"
   label="Date picker dialog"
   format="MM/dd/yyyy"
   value={selectedDate}
   onChange={handleDateChange}
   KeyboardButtonProps={{
   "aria-label": "change date",
     disableUnderline: true
   }}
   InputProps={{
     disableUnderline: true
   }}
/>
```

Searched the [docs](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) but haven't found anything useful which would prevent that.

[Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dsh21?file=/demo.js)

Comment: have you tried `format="MMddyyyy"`

Comment: in your code there is a line `format="MM/dd/yyyy"`. Have you tried to change that line to `format="MMddyyyy"`

Comment: yea but it shows underlines then....

Comment: so does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50432162/12196329

Comment: no if you pass the InputProps with that attribute it does nothing.

Comment: I see no underlines in your sendobox when using  `MM dd yyyy`, in Forefox and Chrome. Also why you don't simply target with CSS and remove it?

Comment: @ikiK because i don t want to polute my code if i can use one property..., check again they are there..

Comment: No underlines in Firefox, Chrome and Safari...

Answer (score 0):

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
   margin="normal"
   id="date-picker-dialog"
   label="Date picker dialog"
   format="MMddyyyy"
   value={selectedDate}
   onChange={handleDateChange}
   maskChar=" "
/>
```

Adding **maskChar** attribute will solve your issue

Comment: not really I want to manually add the slash not it to appear automatically...